# [Replace duplicate value - Python list]

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

Input:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 1}, 
    {'name': 'B', 'value': 5, 'no': 2},
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 3}
] 
request_change_data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'no': 1},
    {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2},
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}
]
```

expected_result:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'no': 1},
    {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2},
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}
]
```

But actual:

```
[
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 1},
    {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2},
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}
]
```

My code is:

```
data = [{'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 5, 'no': 2}, {'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 3}] 

requests = [{'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'no': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2}, {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}]

def test(data, requests):
    for k, v in enumerate(data):
        for request in requests:
            if v['name'] == request['name']:
                v['value'] =request['value']
    return data

print(test(data, requests))
```

How could I change the duplicate stt1 và stt3. I used for to update the value of the key, it always updates only stt3 value is 40.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the code you're using to do this? Please put it into your post.

Comment: My code is here:
data = [{'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 5, 'no': 2}, {'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 3}]

requests = [{'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'stt': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'stt': 2}, {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'stt': 3}]

def test(data, requests):
    for k, v in enumerate(data):
        for request in requests:
            if v['name'] == request['name']:
                v['value'] =request['value']
    return data


print(test(data, requests))

Comment: Please edit that _into your post body_. Stackoverflow comments do not allow multi-line text snippets.

Comment: In your code, you have two dictionaries named `A` in `requests`, so the way you loop will always have "last dictionary wins" for updates, because for each dictionary in `data`, you will iterate through all the dictionaries of `requests`. It _sounds_ like you really want both `name` fields to match as well as `data['no'] == requests['stt']`, yes?

Comment: yes, it is. I am wrong for that, it is actually the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you iterate through `data`, you then iterate over all of the `request` dictionaries, and your code only checks the `name` fields for each dictionary and then updates the `value` field in the dict from `data` if they match.

However, you have multiple dictionaries in `requests` with the same `name`, so  if you were working the first `data` dict:

```
{'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 1}
```

You'd get this in `for request in requests:`

```
Iteration 1: request = {'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'no': 1},
Iteration 2: request = {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2},
Iteration 3: request = {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}
```

So you'd end up updating the `data` dict twice, first with `v['value'] = 35` and then with `v['value'] = 40`.

So for your data, you want to check both `name` and `no` in the dicts and if they both match, then update the fields. Here's a fixed version of your code that does that:

```
data = [{'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 5, 'no': 2}, {'name': 'A', 'value': 19, 'no': 3}]

requests = [{'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'no': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2}, {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}]

# You didn't seem to need the idx from enumerating so I removed it
# You also don't need to return data because lists/dicts are mutable
# types so you're modifying the actual dicts you pass in
def test(data, requests):
    for d in data:
        for request in requests:
            if d['name'] == request['name'] and d['no'] == request['no']:
                d['value'] = request['value']

test(data, requests)
print(data)
```

And I get this output, which is your expected:

```
[
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 35, 'no': 1},
    {'name': 'B', 'value': 10, 'no': 2},
    {'name': 'A', 'value': 40, 'no': 3}
]
```

Comment: Hi, wkl
How about the case I change the 'no' of request_change_data into 'stt'

Comment: @BrianHuynh It'd become `if d['name'] == request['name'] and d['no'] == request['stt']`. Or do you mean you _also_ want `no` to become `stt`?

Comment: Thank you, it is great. I am so stuck with it now i resolved it by you hehe